# Changing dependency property(in ViewModel) hosted to Winform

Tags: wpf, winforms, mvvm, integration

I have `WinForm` application with hosted in it `WPF`(`mvvm`) part. Is it possible to change `dependency property` in `ModelView` from my `WinForm` ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Is it possible to change dependency property in ModelView from my WinForm ?

It is - but your Windows Forms portion would need to understand the WPF types to do it.  You can always use the [wrapper defined when implementing a dependency property](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms753358.aspx#checklist) to call it from code.

If you're hosting a Windows Forms control, however, you'll likely want to make a WPF wrapper that subscribes to the appropriate events on the control, and uses them to set the dependency property.  This way, your Windows Forms portion stays "pure" and doesn't need modification, and your WPF portion can set everything appropriately.

Comment: almost get it : ). Do you know some example of similar solutions ?

Comment: @SergSolohin Not that I can find online.  Basically, your Windows Forms code probably will raise appropriate events, etc (or could).  Make a class that sits in between, listens to that event, and sets the dependency property as needed.